# PHP - Interbase - Call to undefined function ibase_connect()

Tags: php, interbase

I'm trying to connect to a Firebase Database server but I'm getting:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ibase_connect()
```

It was working good, but today it started to throw that error. I've been for the last hours searching on the internet in every page, even in Portuguese, but nothing helps.

Almost in every post they are dealing with W/L/XAMPP, but that doesn't help.

I'm trying this on a valueserver shared host (I don't even know which company is that). PHP Version: 7.2.1

The file is running via cron job.

This is what I'd tried:

1. Verify in php.ini that interbase is uncommented.
2. Look for server errors (none).

Please I don't know what to do.

Comment: what does [phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) say about the extension at runtime?

Comment: seems like the library which contains  ibase_connect() doesn't load.
Make sure hosting settings are still the same. Most likely something was changed - so make it back as it was.

Comment: Hello @Scuzzy here is the PHP Info http://qofgq.hosts.cx/info.php

Comment: @EugeneKapustin the problem is that everything stays the same. I don't even know what had changed

Comment: How much control of your hosting do you have? Like can you actually reconfigure PHP?

Comment: It's important to know whether you are adminstrating your server on your own or you should contact hosting company?  If last, ask them to check what has changes. If you changed nothing, hosting must have changed something!